# Page Object - direct driver.findElement on exact xpath vs. chaining locator via a wrapper

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have a Page Object with two ways of finding the same DOM element:

1. First there's a wrapper for finding the parent transactionsTable, then on this wrapper I call another findElement with the rest of the xpath. This doesn't work in runtime when new instance of Page Object and the actual method is called.
2. a separate method that uses whole xpath directly. This does work.

Of course I'd prefer to use 1st over 2nd due to reusability. Any ideas why it doesn't work?

TransactionsPage:

```
    public WebElement getTransactionsTable() {
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='col d-none d-lg-block']"));
}

public String getNewestTransactionAmount() {
    //this works
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='col d-none d-lg-block']/div[2]//div[@class='col-2 blue-amount text-right']")).getText();
    //this doesn't
    return getTransactionsTable().findElement(By.xpath("/div[2]//div[@class='col-2 blue-amount text-right']")).getText();
}
```

Of course in getNewestTransactionAmount() I'm using only one return - the above is only for example purposes.

Method is called in TransactionTest - first I call the object itself, then it's method:

```
    @Test(groups = {"addAndRemoveNewTransaction"})
public void tc0101_inputNewTransaction() {
    new LoginPage(driver)
            .login()
            .getNavBarComponent()
            .getAddTransactionPage()
            .addAmount(amount)
            .addDate(date)
            .selectCategory("categoryTest")
            .selectSubCategory("subCategoryTest")
            .addLocation(location)
            .selectMethod("paymentTest")
            .selectAccount("accountTest")
            .addNewTransaction();

    TransactionsPage transactionsPage = new NavBarComponent(driver)
            .getTransactionsPage();

    assertEquals(transactionsPage.getNewestTransactionAmount(), amount.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```java
return getTransactionsTable().findElement(By.xpath("/div[2]//div[@class='col-2 blue-amount text-right']")).getText();
```

won't work because you start your xpath from `/`. You need to either add a `.` at the very beginning or remove `/` which will make your path relative.

Another thing is that here

```java
return driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='col d-none d-lg-block']/div[2]//div[@class='col-2 blue-amount text-right']")).getText();
```

you do not actually need to start your path with `.` since your search context here is the entire driver (root of DOM), not a particular part of your page.

Comment: silly mistake, thank you! that helped.